# Rest vs have a rest

Tags: meaning, verbs

Perhaps this question should have been asked on ELL, but I will try here and move there if fail here.

There are verbs (currently I've found *rest*, *walk* and another one I'd better not cite) which can be used also with a verb have (and take) and respective noun (e.g. *rest - have a rest* etc). So basically what is the difference here:

> rest - have a rest, take a rest
>    walk - have a walk

Comment: "I need to rest", "I need a rest", and "I need to take a rest" mean the same thing.  One would not normally say "I need to have a rest", but it's perfectly well understood, and, oddly, it would be fairly natural to say to a companion "Why don't you have a rest while I go scope out the XXX."

Comment: @Hot Licks It depends on which side of the Atlantic _one_ lives on.

Comment: @Hot Licks, Edwin: It's more a matter of *age* than which side of the pond! Wait 'til you guys get old and decrepit, *then* tell me *One would not normally say "I need to have a rest"* (I sometimes need to have a rest before I can muster the energy to stir my first cup of coffee in the morning! :) Also note that the evidence is one would not normally say *I need to **take** a rest* (where ***have*** there is far more common).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I **am** old and decrepit, and I wouldn't say "I need to have a rest" because it takes too much breath to say.